# What is the difference between httpd.exe and httpd.exe -k start?

Tags: php, apache, server, localhost

When I open console window as administrator in the `Apache24/bin` location then I can run the server with both `httpd.exe` and `httpd.exe -k start` command. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

`httpd.exe` starts the apache as console application.

`httpd.exe -k start` starts it as a service.

[Source](http://webauth.stanford.edu/manual/platform/windows.html)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.